# SVG anchor current page highlight

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, anchor

I have an SVG-based menu with links similar to the following.  I'd like to highlight the current page's link (e.g., by adding "font-weight:bold").  Any suggestions?  Should I do something with Javascript?  (Note that I'm linking the SVG in my HTML page via an <object> tag for compatibility, so the solution has to work with that constraint.)  Oh, and I'm fine with the highlight only working in modern browsers.

```
<svg ...>
  <style type="text/css">
a text {
    fill:#ffffff;
}
a:hover text {
    fill:#2020ff;
}
  </style>
  <g>
    <a id="aHome" xlink:href="/" target="_top">
      <text id="txtHome">Home</text>
    </a>
    ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently forgetting about this for a week was worth a bronze badge. :-P

Anyways, the code above is actually correct by itself.  Go figure - I had other overriding CSS styles that caused the a:hover bit to fail.